# UI code: Click on table before it will scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I am working on developing a UI in Visual Studio that has a backend database that you will be able to create rows / edit existing rows. The issue I am having is that at the bottom of my web page lies the table, and when I am scrolling down the page in the browser, as soon as the mouse hits the table my web page stops scrolling and the table starts scrolling instead.

My question is: Is there a way for the page require you to click on the table before it is either active or can scroll?

thanks in advance,

Taylor

Comment: Hi, can you show us your code (HTML /CSS/ JS) ?

Comment: Set the tables overflow to hidden. And then add an event listener to the table so that when clicked it sets the overflow to scroll/auto.